# Know when a view leaves the screen in a Adapter

Tags: java, android

In a row of a ListView I play a video, I'd like to know when the row leaves the screen in order to stop the video and dispose the videoview. There is no problem if the video is paused/removed when the user scrolls up again

How can I do it?

Note: The list have diferent view types so the view is not instantly recycled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your Listview an [OnScrollListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html). It will inform you about scroll changes, and give you the index of the first and last visible items.

@see [setOnScrollListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setOnScrollListener%28android.widget.AbsListView.OnScrollListener%29)

Comment: Thanks for your answer cania. I have some questions about this technique: Imagine that the view at the position 2 is a Video I scroll and, with the help of the OnScrollListener, I see that the view#2 has left the screen. How can I access to that view that is awaiting for another row to be recycled?

Comment: When creating your various Views for your table, can't you keep a reference to the videoplayer-objects that were created? For example: You create an Array with the size of entries in your table. When you create a new videoview (in your getView-method i would assume), you store a reference to its player in the array. When your listview scrolls, you can stop&dispose your videoplayer by using the array.

Comment: Okey, this will be laborious but it seems to be the only option that will work. Thanks again